# Autoencoder in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am building a Tensorflow implementation of an autoencoder for time series. I have a 2000 time series, each of which is a series of 501-time components. These time series are stored in a '.mat' file, which I read in input using scipy.

I then build the autoencoder and train it using batches of the 2000 time series. Finally, I would like to visualize the prediction of the trained autoencoder on the 2000 time series given as input, and compare with the original series, so that I can see if the autoencoder is doing a good job in compressing the data.

I use a double-layer autoencoder, with 250 and 100 nodes in the first and second hidden layer, respectively.

My problem is that when I compare the predicted time series with the original ones, the predicted ones have only positive values, while the original time series have both negative and positive values.

Here the code I have been using:

```
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('input_time_series.mat')

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import fully_connected

input = mat
output = input

tf.reset_default_graph()

num_inputs=501    #number of components in the original time seris
num_hid1=250
num_hid2=100
num_hid3=num_hid1
num_output=num_inputs
lr=0.01
actf=tf.nn.relu

X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,num_inputs])
initializer=tf.variance_scaling_initializer()

w1=tf.Variable(initializer([num_inputs,num_hid1]),dtype=tf.float32)
w2=tf.Variable(initializer([num_hid1,num_hid2]),dtype=tf.float32)
w3=tf.Variable(initializer([num_hid2,num_hid3]),dtype=tf.float32)
w4=tf.Variable(initializer([num_hid3,num_output]),dtype=tf.float32)

b1=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_hid1))
b2=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_hid2))
b3=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_hid3))
b4=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_output))

hid_layer1=actf(tf.matmul(X,w1)+b1)
hid_layer2=actf(tf.matmul(hid_layer1,w2)+b2)
hid_layer3=actf(tf.matmul(hid_layer2,w3)+b3)
output_layer=actf(tf.matmul(hid_layer3,w4)+b4)

loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(output_layer-X))

optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
train=optimizer.minimize(loss)

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()

num_epoch=5000
batch_size=150

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(num_epoch):

        num_batches=2000//batch_size
        for iteration in range(num_batches):
            X_batch = input[:]
            Y_batch = output[:]
            sess.run(train,feed_dict={X:X_batch})

        train_loss=loss.eval(feed_dict={X:X_batch})
        print("epoch {} loss {}".format(epoch,train_loss))


    results=output_layer.eval(feed_dict={X:input})
```

I also include an example of comparison between one input time series (in blue) and the relevant one predicted by the autoencoder (in orange) [image]

Comment: `actf=tf.nn.relu` ? what else do you expect.

Comment: @Vlad thank you, unfortunately I am new to machine learning , so I don't know the exact meaning of all the ingredients in my code. Do you have alternative suggestions?

Comment: try `tf.nn.tanh` instead

Comment: Just don't use an activation function for your output layer.

Comment: @johnhenry, @-kit is right, don't use activation at the output.

Comment: @Kit, thank you, I'm trying to understand the syntax to avoid the activation funciton

Comment: Just don't call it. Write `output_layer=tf.matmul(hid_layer3,w4)+b4` instead of `output_layer=actf(tf.matmul(hid_layer3,w4)+b4)`. But I don't think it's a good way to learn machine learning or TensorFlow if you don't understand what is going on.